# Menu Button not working on Device

Tags: iphone, function, class, button, emulation

```
// On all button click
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); // Prevent event bubbling

    $(this).toggleClass('close'); // Toggle class 'close' of the clicked button
});


// On body click
$('body').on('click', function() {
    if ($('button.close').length) { // Check if any button is having class 'close'
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        $('#cross').removeClass('close'); // Remove 'close' class of '#cross'
    }
});
```

This code does not work on any device. Anyone knows why? The menu button's close class is not appearing on click. The click can be registered but I think is the toggleClass and remove class not working. As menu did pop up meaning to say click might be registered, but class is not activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this:

```
// On all button click
$('button').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); // Prevent event bubbling

    $(this).toggleClass('close'); // Toggle class 'close' of the clicked button
});


// On body click
$('body').on('click touchstart', function() {
    if ($('button.close').length) { // Check if any button is having class 'close'
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        $('#cross').removeClass('close'); // Remove 'close' class of '#cross'
    }
});
```